# Shopping cart App-Xamarin.Forms or Xamarin.iOS or other technology

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I have to make Mobile Native App(s) for Multiplatform(iPhone,Android,etc..) but right now for (iOS-iPhone), and i am .NET guy and also have developed a testing app for Point of Sale by Xamarin.Forms, but right now i have to make real application and that will be publicly available.Here is application details:

This application from 1st day will be Multilingual like, Arabic(1st language) and English (2nd language).

I have to develop a standard shopping cart to view LOT LOT PRODUCTS WITH DIFFERENT IMAGES/ MAY BE VIDEO for each product, and UI SHOULD BE AWESOME/COMPELLING.
Wish List product,Sharing product,Cart info, User Profile, Delivery status, may be in future Map integration to show the status of delivery in Minutes/Kms etc

So i have to finalize the technology, please help me.
Xamarin.Forms or Xamarin.iOS...?

I want the quickest (as developer point of view) and

highly performance (as customer/user point of view).

Thanks,
-NZ

Answer (score 1):

I think for your app your should **go with Native** instead of Forms because you want  AWESOME/COMPELLING UI. for this you need to customize UI controls which is not easy with Xamrin forms.

**developer point of view**

- If you are a .NET guy and know xaml, it will be easier for your to use forms.  With native you will have to learn another plateform to code.    **+1 for Forms**.
- Forms will we quicker as it you can share code for different platform.  **+1 for Forms**
- With forms, you will have to use basic controls available on all plateforms. customizing it for required effect will going to difficult. with Native - You can get maximum of UI. **+1 for Native**

**customer/user point of view**

- App developed with forms are slower at the time of launching  - it slower in initializing. As a user or Customer -- I won't like this. **+1 for Native**
- Adding platform specific functionality later will be easier with native **+1 for Native**
- List item